# Firebase queryEqual with observeSingleEvent

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I want to find set times for a particular artist.

I have a list of Artists

```
artistRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "artists")
```

I have a list of Sets (times)

```
showRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "sets")
```

- artists

  - artist1

    - name: artist 1
  - artist2

    - name: artist 2
- sets

  - set1

    - venueKey: venue1
    - artistKey: artist1
    - time: 1 Jan
  - set2

    - venueKey: venue1
    - artistKey: artist2
    - time: 1 Jan
  - set3

    - venueKey: venue2
    - artistKey: artist1
    - time: 2 Jan

I want to get all artist 1 set times:
[set1, set3]

The following snapshot is returned as null:

```
showRef.queryEqual(toValue: artist?.key, childKey: "artistKey").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
...           
})
```

Is there anything that I'm doing obviously wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `queryOrdered(byChild:)` before the `queryEqual(toValue:)`, like this.

```
showRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "artistKey").queryEqual(toValue: artist?.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
     for set in snapshot.children {
         print("\((set as! FIRDataSnapshot).value)")
     }
})
```

Comment: @grabury Welcome mate :)